# PySimpleGUI Table not automatically refreshing

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pysimplegui

I have a table in my GUI which I'm trying to live update with changing data - I've tried using the refresh() function within the main event loop but outside of the scope of any particular event so that it should be continually refreshed automatically, but for some reason the refresh is only triggered when an event is. Clearly I'm confused about the logic behind some of this library so advice would be appreciated, thanks! Sample code (make_data() is just a function generating random data to test the update speed):

```
class GUI():
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.layout = [
            [sg.Table(
                values=data[1:],
                headings=data[0],
                max_col_width=25,
                num_rows=20,
                alternating_row_color='green',
                key='-TABLE-',
                enable_events=True,
                enable_click_events=True,
                justification='center',
                )],
            [sg.Text("", size=(50, 1), expand_x=True, key='-Position-')]
            ]
        
        self.window = sg.Window('Table', self.layout, finalize=True)
        self.table = self.window['-TABLE-']
        self.position = self.window['-Position-']
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.window['-TABLE-'].update(values = make_data(10,10))
            self.window.refresh()
            self.event, self.values = self.window.read()
            if self.event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                break
            elif isinstance(self.event, tuple) and self.event[0:2] == ('-TABLE-', '+CICKED+'):       
                row, col = self.event[2]
                selection = self.values['-TABLE-']
                previous_select_row = selection[0] if selection else 'None'
                

GUI().run()
```

My understanding was that this should refresh which each loop and also execute logic if certain events trigger, yet in practice the refresh() step is only triggering when another event is

Comment: Method `read` of `sg.Window` will block the while loop if no event. You can add option `timeout=1000` in method `read`, then it will generate an event `sg.TIMEOUT_KEY` each 1000 milliseconds, so update your table under the case `elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_KEY:`. `window.refresh()` is not required for next statement is the `read` which will refresh GUI.

Comment: Ah I was unaware .read() had that effect - works great now, thanks!

Comment: Why does this have `Tkinter` as a tag?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect - you should use `tk.mainloop()` i/o a `while` loop; triggering refreshes could be done at regular time intervals with the use of `tk.after()`